# Installing 18.04 on a preexisting Ubuntu 16.04 LVM setup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, lvm

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my computer.

I have one harddrive that looks like so:

```
 sda
 - sda1: /boot/efi
 - sda2: /boot
 - sda3: [LVM:ubuntu-mate-vg]
   - swap_1
     - cryptswap1
   - /home
   - /
```

Now when I use the 18.04 Live USB it is unable to detect any existing OS. What I would like to know: how can I install the 18.04 on a new LVM partition, keeping my existing setup functional? I will of course shrink my existing setup and make space, but I'm concerned about: where do I pick to be the boot partition of this new install? where do I place the root? How would I add it to grub?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it is unable to see the block devices at all.  Is the disk encrypted?
You would have to shrink your system first: probably make /home and / small.
Then you would create a new "root" (call it "root18") on which you'd install.
You ought to be able to share the same /boot.

Unfortunately, I'm here because it appears that the ubuntu18 install ISO won't let me pick an existing /boot to mount.